# distribute android app through Google Play and as .apk file directly

Tags: android

I have built an application that we will be selling to customers through the Google Play store.

We also have individuals in house that will support outside customers, and also use it in house.  They need to have the application running on their own device.  If I distribute it to them via an .apk file, can they receive updates via Google Play?  Or do they have to purchase it through Google Play to receive updates?

Secondary question: Is there a better solution to distributing to internal users?

Comment: It is using LVL. The app will check to see if the user has purchased the app. If it is determined it is not licensed, the user can enter a password based on the ANDROID_ID. The in house users can request the password in house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following in an email from a member of the Google Play Team:

"The side-loaded apps used by your internal users will not receive updates from Google Play. You will need to provide them with the new APK in order for them to access the new features/functionality. This is working as intended to ensure that only users who have purchased a paid app will receive notifications and updates."

So: Paid for apps cannot be updated via Google Play if they are "side-loaded" (installed outside of Google Play).

Answer (score 2):

As curious myself and not having official info on this, I just did a test:

On Google Play I have an App at version 1.3.2

- I've installed via ADB the version 1.3.0 on my device.
- Opened Google Play > My Apps.
- The update to version 1.3.2 was available.
- Did the update

All seems to work normally.

So my word on this is: Yes they will receive the update (the app has to have the same signature of course).
Maybe you might just have a look on term of services if this isn't breaking any rules.

On the second question, the "better" solution may wary based on the company infrastructure which we don't know.

Comment: I searched the terms of service and did not see anything that would restrict this type of distribution.  Can you comment on @dagalpin's answer?  If it is not free, do you think that this will still work?

Comment: For the purchase situation, I think it should work as long as you don't use the Google Play Licensing because if you don't actually buy the app, for the system you are not considered as a rightful owner.

Comment: I've got a solution for the licensing issue.  Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work for me.  Both are signed with the same signature, but the update does not show up in google play.  It just says it can open it.

Comment: I think that is just a bug with Google Play, that same problem happen to me with Angry Birds updates. Also make sure you are not viewing a Google Play cached page, if you check just after uploading an update it may not be visible right away.

Comment: Is the app you tested free or for sale?  I think the difference is that if the app is for sale, it will not be updated unless it was purchased through Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

If the version on Google Play is identical to the version you distributed, signed with the same signature, and it is available as a free app, then Google Play can be used to update the version distributed outside of Google Play.

Comment: What if it is not free, but sold?  Will it still update as @BrainCrash describes?